# Specifying a maxDuration in vercel.json for an Express.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js, vercel

I've upgraded to a Pro plan in hosting my Express app on Vercel. I expected that the maxDuration should have been increased from the default 10 seconds t0 60 seconds (for the pro plan) but it seems I have to explicitly specify the maxDuration value in my vercel.json file. Here's my vercel.json:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./server.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/server.js"
    }
  ],
  "functions": {
    "controllers/*.js": {
      "maxDuration": 60
    },
    "middleware/**/*.js": {
      "maxDuration": 60
    }
  }
}
```

When I commit and successfully pushed to Github, Github shows an error-based notification from Vercel that says "Conflicting functions and builds Configuration" which clearly says that in my vercel.json file I can't use the "builds" and the "functions" command together; I can only use either of them.

I tried deleting the "builds" command. Upon pushing again, Vercel couldnt interprete/convert my Express.js controller functions/files into serverless functions. Though I know that the build command is definitely necessary.

I really need help. How can I do the configuration in a way that I can set a maxDuration so that my API doesn't timeout after the default 10 seconds?
Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I'm facing the exact same issue : ExpressJS server deployed on Vercel using vercel.json configured exactly like you. I am using the "pro" plan as well. Did you find a solution to configure de timeout duration ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're grappling with conflicting configurations between "builds" and "functions" while setting maxDuration for your Express.js APIs on Vercel, fret not! Here's a straightforward solution to help you out.

According to the Vercel documentation, you can adjust your vercel.json file to smoothly handle this issue. Let's dive in:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./server.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node",
      "functions": {
        "controllers/*.js": { "maxDuration": 60 },
        "middleware/**/*.js": { "maxDuration": 60 }
      }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    { "src": "/(.*)", "dest": "/server.js" }
  ]
}
```

By including the "functions" configuration within the "builds" section as demonstrated, you can seamlessly deploy your Express.js application on Vercel. Plus, with the specified maxDuration of 60 seconds for your serverless functions, you'll steer clear of any untimely timeouts.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, unfortunatly, it breaks the build : `The vercel.json schema validation failed with the following message: builds[0] should NOT have additional property functions`. And if I put the "functions" attribute into "config" it is ignored and the timeout is still 10 seconds

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues but with FastAPI (python). Tried adding functions to verce.json but getting:

```
Vercel CLI 33.1.0 Error: Invalid vercel.json - should NOT have additional property `functions`. Please remove it.
```

**Edit**

Based on [this](https://github.com/vercel/vercel/blob/c2d99855ea6132380434ed29643120680f95fad7/packages/build-utils/src/types.ts#L36) it should probably go under `config`:

```json
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./server.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node",
      "config": {
        "functions": {
          "controllers/*.js": { "maxDuration": 60 },
          "middleware/**/*.js": { "maxDuration": 60 }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    { "src": "/(.*)", "dest": "/server.js" }
  ]
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Vercel support suggested this:

*We don't typically recommend using 'builds' property anymore and it's even mentioned in the vercel.json docs "We recommend against using this property.": https://vercel.com/docs/projects/project-configuration#builds*

They suggested to use something like this:

```
{
  "rewrites": [
    { "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "app/server.js" }
  ],
  "functions": {
    "app/server.js": {
      "maxDuration": 60
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thank for the answer BUT 

1- the first method doesn't change anything and the timeout is still of 10 seconds

2- the second method breaks the build with this error:

`Error: The pattern "www-api-dev.js" defined in functions doesn't match any Serverless Functions inside the api directory."`

It seems that using "functions" needs to be done in addition of using the api directory serverless functions which defies the goal of using an independant expressjs server

Answer (score 0):

> Directly setting `maxDuration` for a custom server setup (like an
> Express app) through vercel.json isn't supported due to Vercel's focus
> on serverless functions. For applications requiring longer execution
> times, deploying your application as a Docker container on Vercel
> might be a more suitable approach.

Example Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14    
WORKDIR /usr/src/app    
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=production
COPY . ./    
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

While Docker itself doesn't have a `maxDuration` setting, you can control how your application runs within Docker using HEALTHCHECK/Keep-Alive based on your requirement:
e.g.

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=30s --timeout=30s --start-period=5s --retries=3 \
  CMD [ "node", "healthcheck.js" ]
```

> If your goal is to explicitly set a maximum duration for requests, this would typically be managed within your application logic in a Dockerized setup, rather than through Vercel's configuration.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.get('/long-running', (req, res) => {
  // Set a timeout for the request
  const timeout = 60000; // 60 seconds
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    res.status(408).send('Request timed out');
  }, timeout);

  // Your long-running operation
  someLongRunningOperation().then((result) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    res.send(result);
  }).catch((error) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    res.status(500).send(error.message);
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```